# Bug in online editor with xml?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

Recently I was answering question with something like this ...

> In the xml file you want to link to your `style.xslt` use
>
> ```
> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xslt"?>
> ```

I had to divide the line

> In the xml file you want to link to your `style.xslt` use

and line

> ```
> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xslt"?>
> ```

with newline, in other case I got just

> In the xml file you want to link to your `style.xslt` use

ignoring the second line, is this a bug?
Is it at least documented somewhere?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a backtick in the first block you listed? It appears after "use" in the other blocks.

Comment: You know the difference between code blocks and quotes? If not: [Markdown help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) helps.

Comment: edited, I copied it wrong, important thing is to notify that I used `` for xml line

Comment: just quoted it for this meta post, at SO I used the first line as plain text and second line as code block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's intentional, since Markdown supports [hard-wrapped paragraphs](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) which come with the requirement that text in different blocks is separated by one or more blank lines.

So, without the blank line, the Markdown parser sees your original syntax as a single line that contains some spaces followed by unescaped XML (that's stripped by the sanitizer), instead of a paragraph followed by an indented code block.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent XML blocks by 4 characters to get the code formatting to kick in and any sort of formatting requires a blank line before it before it works. I'm not sure if it's just a Markdown limitation or if that's just how Stack Exchange implements it, but either way this seems like it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) to me.

Answer (score 0):

The code block must be separated with an empty line from the previous text.

If you write the following text, it will not appear as you want, even though the code is indented with four spaces.

```
In the xml file you want to link to your style.xslt use
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xslt"?>
```

The text would appear as:

In the xml file you want to link to your style.xslt use

Add an empty line, and you get what you want:

In the xml file you want to link to your style.xslt use

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xslt"?>
```